# How to set a RatingBar as indicator with fixed stars without triggering OnRatingBarChangeListener

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, ratingbar

I'm trying to allow users to put their rating of a service , and I want to prevent user from adding rating twice , the problem is when, a user has already rated the service and I retrieve stars number from firebase and place them in the rating bar , the OnRatingBarChaneListener gets triggered and it adds value to the firebase again .
this is my code please help me .

```
   final DatabaseReference r = database.getReference("rating");
    r.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            for (final DataSnapshot snapshot5 : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                final Rating rt = snapshot5.getValue(Rating.class);
                final String ratingId= snapshot5.getKey();
                               // Toast.makeText(InfoService.this,key,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                assert rt != null;
                if(!(rt.getId().equals(account.getUid())) && (rt.getIdservice().equals(key))) {
                    RatingB.setOnRatingBarChangeListener(new RatingBar.OnRatingBarChangeListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onRatingChanged(RatingBar ratingBar, float rating, boolean fromUser) {

                            String rateId = r.push().getKey();

                            // Toast.makeText(InfoService.this,"thank you for voting"+key,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            Rating rate = new Rating(rateId,account.getUid(),key,rating);
                            r.child(rateId).setValue(rate);
                            //  int stars = Math.round(rating);
                            RatingB.setRating(rating);
                            RatingB.setIsIndicator(true);


                        }
                    });



                                }else {
                    textrate.setText("Votre evaluation");
                    RatingB.setIsIndicator(true);
                    RatingB.setRating(rt.getStar());

                }


                }

                            }



        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`onRatingChanged` has a parameter `boolean fromUser`, from the [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RatingBar.OnRatingBarChangeListener?hl=nn):

> **boolean**: True if the rating change was initiated by a user's touch
>   gesture or arrow key/horizontal trackbell movement.

I think you just need to check if this value is `True` before sending the new rating to `Firebase`